# Multiple iOS Apps subscribed to the same BLE characteristic

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Is it possible to have multiple iOS apps (on the same device) subscribed to the same periphierial characteristic in indicate mode?
Is there any assurance that all of the apps will receive all of the packets?

Answer (score 0):

Almost not possible.You can make different tasks under one APP such that each task connects through its dedicated characteristics. 
Better make different apps (app type of ui) and link each app with each characteristics.